# В чём заключается ошибка между SETTER/GETTER на JAVA?

Tags: java

Дорогие пользователи! Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку при наследовании классов книги и класса Book. "Идея" подчёркивает мои GETTER и SETTER и говорит о разных типах данных (enum и стринги). Суть задачи в том, чтобы показать, в какой статус книга перейти может, а в какой нет при помощи наследования и оператора switch. Буду Вам благодарен! П.С.: условия задачи я поменять не могу, т.е. это конкретно 4 класса-наследника и супер-класс BookMover. Код прилагаю:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Book book = new Book("The Great Gatsby");
        BookMover fromArchivedStatusMover = new FromArchievedStatusMover();
        fromArchivedStatusMover.moveToStatus(book, Status.AVAILABLE);
        System.out.println(book.getStatus());

        BookMover fromAvailableStatusMover = new FromAvailableStatusMover();
        fromAvailableStatusMover.moveToStatus(book, Status.BORROWED);
        System.out.println(book.getStatus());

        BookMover fromBorrowedStatusMover = new FromBorrowedStatusMover();
        fromBorrowedStatusMover.moveToStatus(book, Status.OVERDUED);
        System.out.println(book.getStatus());

        BookMover fromOverduedStatusMover = new FromOverduedStatusMover();
        fromOverduedStatusMover.moveToStatus(book, Status.AVAILABLE);
        System.out.println(book.getStatus());

    }
}
public class Book {
    protected String title;
    protected String status;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
public class BookMover {

    protected void moveToStatus(Book book, Status requestedStatus) {
        System.out.println("Moving status...");
    }
}
public class FromArchievedStatusMover extends BookMover {

    @Override
    protected void moveToStatus(Book book, Status requestedStatus) {
        switch (book.status) {
            case Status.AVAILABLE:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Перевод книги из статуса 'X' в статус 'Y' невозможен");
                break;
        }
    }
}
public class FromAvailableStatusMover extends BookMover {

    @Override
    protected void moveToStatus(Book book, Status requestedStatus) {
        switch (book.status) {
            case Status.BORROWED:
                break;
            case Status.ARCHIEVED:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Перевод книги из статуса 'X' в статус 'Y' невозможен");
                break;
        }
    }
}
public class FromBorrowedStatusMover extends BookMover {

    @Override
    protected void moveToStatus(Book book, Status requestedStatus) {
        switch (book.status) {
            case Status.AVAILABLE:
                break;
            case Status.OVERDUED:
                break;
            case Status.ARCHIEVED:
                break;
        }
    }
}
public class FromOverduedStatusMover extends BookMover {

    @Override
    protected void moveToStatus(Book book, Status requestedStatus) {
        switch (book.status) {
            case Status.AVAILABLE:
                break;
            case Status.ARCHIEVED:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Перевод книги из статуса 'X' в статус 'Y' невозможен");
                break;
        }
    }
}
public enum Status {

    AVAILABLE,
    BORROWED,
    ARCHIEVED,
    OVERDUED;
}
```

Comment: Ну как бы да, `Status requestedStatus` и `String status` это и в самом деле абсолютно разные типы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

исправьте

```
protected String status;
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

на

```
protected Status status;
public void setStatus(Status status) {
      this.status = status;
}
```

Вы намешали типы String и Status